# Cannot resolve symbol Youtube in Android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am really frustrated with this I followed all the steps to add the google api for youtube in my android project and I still having this error: **Cannot resolve symbol Youtube**

Here is my java class:

```
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
import  com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;


import java.util.List;




public class VideoCatalogActivity extends Activity implements YouTubeThumbnailLoader, YouTubePlayer{

    private static final String TAG =  VideoCatalogActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static Youtube youtube;

    GridView videosGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

and this is my app gradle file:

```
     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev178-1.22.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: Which line causes the problem? Does the error actually have `Youtube` or is it `youtube` or `YouTube`? In this situation, the difference is probably negligible. However, for future reference, you should copy and paste error messages in order to avoid these kinds of typos that can cause confusion for anyone who wants to help you.

Comment: the line causing the problem is this one :    private static Youtube youtube;

Comment: Remember that Java is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem the declaration was wrong: i had to declare youtube as YouTube object not Youtube.